# Not able to see '/home' drive

Tags: partitioning, drive

I have installed "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" with 3 partition:

- `/` drive for 100 GB
- `/home` for 200 GB and
- `/swap` drive for 8 GB

But after successful installation I'm not able to see `/home` drive .

I can see only `/` drive. I want to keep my data's in `/home` drive [as like `D:` drive in windows] .

Answer (score 0):

If you've not started to really use it the simplest way to do this would be reinstall using the Something Else option at partition stage, editing partitions and choosing the correct mount points.

Otherwise you'll need to copy data from the existing `/home` into the new partition.

If you want to just add the partition to `/etc/fstab` and have it mount that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first you need to make one thing clear: what utility/tool did you use to see what partitions you have?

If you are referring to Nautilus(the default file manager which opens your home folder/documents etc), then it would not show you the drives explicitly.

Just to be sure, open your dash and search for system monitor

[image]

and select the filesystems tab.

[image]

if you see home here, that means your home partition is in use.so whatever files you put in your home folder[Desktop, pictures,videos and all other folders inside Home will go into your home drive]

Answer (score 0):

The windows concept of a "drive" does not exist on Linux systems. As you wrote, you *mounted* the 200GB partition you created under `/home`, and that is where it is located. There is no separate "drive" for that partition; instead, access to partitions happens transparently, i.e. every time you access something below `/home`, like `/home/user/Desktop`, you'll be accessing your 200GB partition.

So, if you really set it up like you said you did (you can use [Sagar_R's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/127558/19083) to check that), everything is already as it should be.